# Call a CSS rule in the statement of another CSS rule?

Tags: css

Can I call a rule in the statement of another rule if CSS?. Something like this:

```
.myFirstRule
{
    color: white;
}

.mySecondRule
{
    width: 1000px;
    myFirstRule;
}
```

Thank you.

*Sorry about my english*

Comment: In CSS, no.  However, you can apply styles to more than one selector, such as:

.myFirstRule, .mySecondRule {color: white;}  

Make sure you separate the two selectors with a comma.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky - This should be an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 4):

In CSS, no you cannot.  You can, however, apply styles to more than one selector at a time, such as:

```
.myFirstRule, .mySecondRule { color: white; }
```

Make sure each selector is separated with a comma, and you're good to go.

Comment: The second Rule is called from another file

Comment: That doesn't matter.  Just because a selector exists in one CSS file does not mean it cannot exist in the other.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in plain CSS but there are two solutions to your problem:

**One:** Use multiple selectors

```
<div class="myFirstRule mySecondRule"></div>
```

**Two:** Use SASS (or LESS, I suppose)

```
.myFirstRule {
  color: white;
}
.mySecondRule {
  width: 1000px;
  .myFirstRule;
}
```

*Alternatively*, still with SASS, you could also do this with a mixin:

```
// Define here
@mixin reusableRule {
  color: white;
}

.myFirstRule {
  @include reusableRule;
}
.mySecondRule {
  width: 1000px;
  @include reusableRule;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in pure CSS.. You can use a comma or `,` to apply a property to multiple selectors

Try this:

```
.myFirstRule, .mySecondRule {
    color:white;
}

.mySecondRule
{
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: The second Rule is called from another file

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with normal CSS, but you could try using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) instead, which both compile to CSS. They allow this behavior through "mixins".

For example in LESS you could do:

```
.myFirstRule
{
    color: white;
}

.mySecondRule
{
    width: 1000px;
    .myFirstRule;
}
```

which would generate CSS:

```
.myFirstRule
{
    color: white;
}

.mySecondRule
{
    width: 1000px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: The second Rule is called from another file

Comment: LESS and SASS both merge multiple files into a single .CSS file for deployment, so separating the rules into files based on their responsibility is ideal. So yes, LESS and SASS would both allow you to include one rule into another when they are in separate files.